# Recover $_GET var in ajax

Tags: ajax

When having some $_GET information in the URL, for example: index.php?WhatIWant=1. How do we recover that value using ajax?

I tried to recover it using $_GET['WhatIwant'] in the php part, like this:

PHP:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['WhatIwant'];

?>
```

jQuery:

```
$.post('functions/test.php',function(test)
{
    $('.value').text(test);
});
```

but I keep getting the "undefined index: WhatIwant", which I guess makes sense. But then how recover it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is returning undefined is because you are posting to functions/test.php which will not have the $_GET var set.

If you wan't to be able to access it in javascript I would suggest something like the following:

```
var randomGet = <?php echo(isset($_GET['random']) ? '"' .$_GET['random']. '"' : ''); ?>;
alert(randomGet);
```